# Variable list creates lists inside lists

Tags: python

I am creating a program that is supposed to append dictionaries to a list in a different (`.txt`) file. The program automatically creates a list in the file, once the file is read into a variable. Saving a dictionary to the file for the first time shows no problems, but the second time it becomes a list inside a list. The third time random slashes get added.

I have already tried erasing the file by closing it and opening it with `"w"` mode. The variable keeps adding lists. Using `truncate()` some unknown characters appear at the excact length of the new list. 
My code is:

```py
file = "Commands.txt"
commandtext= open("Commands.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
text= commandtext.readlines()
#here the file already became a list, even if i dont want it to be.
print(text)
exit= False

while exit == False:
    Input = input("For help type help or ? > ")
    if Input.lower() == "new":
        #vraag om de variabelen
        commandVar = input("Enter the new command's name: ")
        triggerVar = input("Enter the trigger the PA should react to: ")
        responseVar = input("Enter the response the PA should give: ")
        #voeg de naam, trigger en response toe aan de dictionary en de list
        #Here we overwrite the list with the addition of an extra dictionary
        text.append({
                "Command Name": commandVar,
                "Command Trigger": triggerVar,
                "Command Response": responseVar,
        })
        #now the variable isn't appended to, but contains a list inside of a list
        print(text)
        #maak het bestand leeg en voeg de commando's toe
        #now we append to the file, saving the variable with the distorted list
        commandtext.close()
        commandfile= open("Commands.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        commandfile.write(str(text))
        print("Command saved, to clear cache we are stopping the program")
        print(text)
        exit = True
```

the expected results are dictionaries inside the list defining the command, but for every dictionary, a new list is created

Comment: You need to store your data in a properly serialised format, like JSON, or pickle it, or *something*. At the moment you're just relying on the implicit string representation of a Python list, but `readlines` does not parse that list as list, it just returns a *list of lines*.

Comment: `readlines` will return a list, you then append a dictionary to that (not a list), what are you actually trying to add to the list?

Comment: I am trying to add dictionaries into a list, to read them out later. But instead of having one list, every dictionary gets its own list. I didn't know readlines actually did that, thanks.
Now, how do i read from a file without creating a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to use`read` instead of `readlines` in order to remove the creation of the list. As [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) stated:

> `readlines` does not parse that list as list, it just returns a *list of lines*.

`read` however just makes a string from the whole file.